# How to add center margin in flashcards package?

Tags: positioning, flashcards

The flashcards package accepts a `.cfg` file specifying layout of flashcards on the page, including `# rows/columns`, `top` margin, `left` margin for odd/even pages, etc.  I don't see any way to add a center margin between columns.

**EDIT**: As for instance would be needed for something like Avery 8859.

For a 2 column layout, the columns are immediately adjacent to each other, but I would like to add a `0.5"` margin between them.  What would it take to add that?  Does this necessitate digging into the package's source code?

current curr.cfg:

```
\newcommand{\cardpapermode}{portrait}
\newcommand{\cardpaper}{letterpaper}
\newcommand{\cardrows}{5}
\newcommand{\cardcolumns}{2}
\setlength{\cardheight}{2.0in}
\setlength{\cardwidth}{3.5in}
\setlength{\topoffset}{0.50in}
\setlength{\oddoffset}{0.75in}
\setlength{\evenoffset}{0.75in}
```

mwe.tex

```
\documentclass[curr,grid]{flashcards}
\begin{document}
\begin{flashcard}{1}a\end{flashcard} \begin{flashcard}{2}b\end{flashcard} \begin{flashcard}{3}c\end{flashcard} \begin{flashcard}{4}d\end{flashcard} \begin{flashcard}{5}e\end{flashcard} \begin{flashcard}{6}f\end{flashcard} \begin{flashcard}{7}g\end{flashcard} \begin{flashcard}{8}h\end{flashcard} \begin{flashcard}{9}i\end{flashcard} \begin{flashcard}{10}j\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
\endinput
```

Current output:

[image: current output]

What I'd like to see:

[image: center margin flashcard]

**UPDATE:** I don't see a way to do this through the cfg, since that just sets outer margins.  So looking at the .cls file, I'm *guessing* I may be able to functionally create a margin by inserting a box between the two columns of each row (box = 0.5" wide and same height as cards).  If so, I'm trying to find out where the right place to do that is: the \whiledo section at line 105 or in the \newenvironment{flashcard} section at 278.  Does that sound like the right direction?

Comment: I don't quite follow the purpose of your link, it just seems to say "use flashcards pkg". What did I miss?

Comment: Ah I see.  curr.cfg is identical to Avery5371.cfg.  What I'd like to do is find a way to edit the .cfg (or edit the package code) so there's space between the columns.

Comment: After further study, there is no way to get a gap using [grid].  You can get a gap by using [frame] and specifying `\cardmargin`.  Alas, this affect both the height and width.